# about the LyX bibliographystyle{} command

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I'm working on LyX with a template which has its own `\bibliographystyle{}` command.

when I using the compiling command, with an error reporting:

```
 Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 28 of file
```

I guess it is caused by the following line which is automatically generated by LyX:

`\bibliographystyle{plain}`

can I just disable this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the style used by the template is one available in LyX, I would suggest removing the `\bibliographystyle` from the template, and changing the style used by LyX. You can do that by right clicking the bibliography inset and choosing Settings.

If that is not the case, you can try the following:

1. Move the bibliography inset into a comment, by selecting it and choosing Insert -> Note --> Comment.
2. Look in the source panel (View -> Code preview pane), and find the `\bibliography` command:

   [image]

   Here I've already placed the bibliography inset into a comment. You can see I have `\bibliography{IEEEexample}`. (Note that if you choose *LyX Note* instead of *Comment* in the previous steph, the `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle` will not be visible in the source panel.)
3. Copy  `\bibliography{<filename>}` command from the source panel.
4. Add an ERT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or Insert -> Tex code) right after the comment inset with the bibliography, and paste  `\bibliography{<filename>}` into it:

   [image]

The reason for keeping the bibliography inset like that is to make citations available via the LyX GUI. If you just have the ERT with `\bibliography{...}` LyX won't parse that file for citations, I think.